# Как сделать репозиторий на гите в кодировке 1251?

Tags: git

Необходимо поменять с UTF8 на 1251 отображение кода на гите.

Comment: Что значит "отображение на гите"? Он не должен ничего знать о кодировках. Просто поменяйте ее в любом редакторе.

Comment: вы правы, неверно выразился, отображение на платформе, использующая контроль версий GIT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начиная с версии 2.18.* можно сделать так в файле .gitattributes:

```
* working-tree-encoding=CP1251 eol=CRLF
```

Comment: Лучший , просто лучший. Решил мою проблему и все костыли. Спасибо.

Comment: @Maxim_wizard, основной-то костыль (cp1251 вместо utf8) как раз остался на месте.

Comment: Просто ЯП 32 битный.

Comment: @Maxim_wizard Непонятно, если ЯП 32-битный, причём тут вообще кодировки в Git?